# ¿Como encuentro diferencias entre registros de dos tablas "iguales" en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin

Hola tengo dos tablas en MySQL `inventario1` e `inventario2` ambas tablas en escencia deberían ser idénticas, sin embargo, quiero ver si entre sus registros existen diferencias, pero lo quiero hacer desde MySQL con alguna consulta

He intentado esto, pero no es el resultado que espero

```
SELECT inventario.consecutivo FROM inventario WHERE inventario.consecutivo NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT inventario2.consecutivo from inventario2)
```

Me gustaría que me dijera los registros donde existen diferencias

De antemano muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Qué versión de MySQL está usando?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes intentar con esta sentencia, donde utilizamos la clausula **NOT EXISTS**, seleccionamos el campo deseado a comparar de las dos tablas, asignamos un identificador *a,b* para identificarlos y con **where** comparamos ese mismo campo, así traemos los datos del primer **select** que no esta en el segundo, ejemplo:

```
SELECT inventario.consecutivo FROM inventario a WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT inventario2.consecutivo FROM inventario2 b
WHERE a.consecutivo= b.consecutivo);
```

Hay muchas maneras, pero esta es la mas sencilla a mi parecer, dime si te sirvió.

Comment: El problema es que ambas tablas tienen más de 50 campos y necesito comparar todos contra todos

Answer (score 2):

Puedes intenar con la instruccion minus tambien.

```
SELECT consecutivo 
FROM inventario 
MINUS 
SELECT consecutivo 
from inventario2
```

Con esa instruccion vas a obtener los consecutivos que se encuentren en la tabla 1 y no se encuentren en la 2.

Si quieres obtenerlos a la inversa, utiliza el mismo query, volteando el orden de las tablas.

Comment: ¿Desde qué versión de MySQL hay soporte a MINUS?. Desde MariaDB 10.6.1 existe soporte a [MINUS](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/minus/#:~:text=MINUS%20was%20introduced%20as%20a%20synonym%20for%20EXCEPT%20from%20MariaDB%2010.6.1.).